# is it advisable to use php for creating a billing system?

Tags: php

a client(hotelier) approached  me asking if i could develop a billing and accounts system for his restaurant. and i responded positively. now the only programming languages i am good at is PHP and MySQL. and of course(HTML,CSS & JS).

do you think i should go ahead and build the application using PHP and install it in his system. or else just ask him to find another vendor to build the app.?

thank you

Comment: Can they/you use an existing one?  There are probably free ones out there that you can use wholesale, or existing libraries that you leverage in your custom app.

Comment: Does this have any connection to their website? I.e. is it a web app?

Comment: It seems there is no need to develop something like that from the scratch.

Comment: i am thinking of making it as web app. because then i can make it as e-commerce oriented to take orders and process it and merge it with existing accounts database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is definitely in a position you can use to build all sorts of applications. You can build blogs, ecommerce sites, forums, ERPs, financial applications and more.

If you find yourself good at PHP, you can go ahead definitely.

As opposed to a software/exe, you will have to train the users as to how to configure the server, etc to run the application just in case other than the manual/help you might want to provide.

Soucrecode visibility is another thing that others/applications users can view. If you are worried, you can licence your application.

Comment: thank you for the advice. and this is what i might do as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Go for it. PHP is possible in almost all types of applications. The good side of PHP is it is server-side so your code is encapsulated thus minimize (though not all) hacking.

However, if you have already had an existing software/program, better optimize it or make it more efficient. Thanks.